Resonant frequency of multi diameter closed pipe
I'm trying to make sense of how resonances in pipes work.
I gather that, in the instance below, the fundamental resonant frequency of the 1m closed pipe (ignoring end correction etc.) is
$$ f_{0} = \frac{c}{4 L} = \frac{343}{4 \times 1} \approx 86 \textrm{Hz}\ . \tag{1} $$

However, in the instance below, where the pipe sharply changes diameter, what would the resonant frequency be? Would there be two fundamental resonant frequencies?


There will be refections at the diameter jump point becaase of the impedence mismatch.  This will  the problem will be rather more complicated: a two-dimensional eigenvalue problem.
